# After having pirated software on my computer, is it forever haram?

Tags: halal-haram, piracy, software

I pirate and I watch pornographic materials. Before you say, yes, I regret my actions and am trying to change myself. I have been told that my laptop (thus my OS and everything in it) is haram only when I watch pornographic material (unsure if it's the same case if I were pirating) but I have doubts on that.

1. If I pirate a program, my system is forever affected. It doesn't matter if I uninstall or delete it, there will always be trace amounts, somewhere. Because of that, wouldn't it make my entire laptop not halal too? It applies if I were to watch pornographic materials too, right?

   - If I were to use an account (such as the one I'm using right now) on the non-halal laptop, it would make the account not halal too? If I were to use the now not halal account on another laptop (that's halal), it would make it not halal too for the reasons stated in 1), correct?
2. If doing haram things like those two would make the entire laptop haram, what I gained after doing such things would also be haram. So if I were to gain knowledge (I plan to) through it, my education would be in vain?

I personally hope that point 1 and 2 are wrong. Especially because it's close to impossible for me to avoid it now. I can't even use my laptop to stop using it if it were true.

3. I mentioned about education. What if even the tiniest bit of knowledge I gained through this (now) non-halal laptop were to be used to get a job or even to use it in a job? Would all my provisions be not halal if I were to buy them with the pay I gained through the job?
4. What if, that if I weren't to do something haram like aforementioned, I wouldn't be doing something good/gaining something(such as getting closer to Allah SWT, pay, knowledge, etc). If I am able and did those things only because of something haram, would what I gain be halal?

Answer (score -1):

About your laptop. Assume a building is used for shirk. This building is then turned into a mosque. Is the building forever haram ?

If you think so, your laptop is probably haram too.

If you do not think so, then your laptop is fine. Note that plenty of old mosques are in that case. It is just a building, it doesn't oblige you to do anything in it.

I know a bit about chaos theory. What is your question exactly ? I don't see the link with your laptop. And I suggest you ask in another post.